# Angularjs 1.4.8 not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

https://jsfiddle.net/basickarl/4behds2y/3/

I'm running a `IE10 on Win8` VM from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

The fiddle linked works in Chrome:
[image]

However does not work in IE10:
[image]

Neither the curly brackets or the ng-click seems to not work.

Also on my localhost (I'm running a nodejs server) I get the following error: `SCRIPT5009: 'angular' is undefined` (I'm guessing it's the same issue with fiddle). I tried setting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1">` but still doesn't work.

I have the following includes in my body:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.6.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Both fiddle and my localhost code work in IE9 and IE11.

Comment: Are you running your app from a webserver?

Comment: @vitozev Localhost server yes (nodejs) with access to the internet. Then the fiddle also (which is up on the web).

Answer (score 0):

I let the Windows 8 software update on the VM and now IE10 is working with everything.

So if you download the VM's from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/ update them the first thing you do.